# adjusted R2 for conditional constrained ordination

Tags: r, partial, vegan, adjustment, rda

After a model selection of a partial ordination, is it correct to apply the function RsquareAdj(mod.sel) to get the adjusted R2?
Or is it correct to use Ezekiel's formula in a straightforward manner?

[image: From Borcard et al. 2011. Numerical Ecology with R]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that **vegan** does not do it in straightforward way. The function is not exported, but use `vegan:::RsquareAdj.rda` to see how the partial models are handled. If everything else fails, you may also consider looking at the documentation which reads

> The raw R-squared of partial ‘rda’ gives the proportion explained
>        after removing the variation due to conditioning (partial) terms;
>        Legendre et al. (2011) call this semi-partial R-squared. The
>        adjusted R-squared is found as the difference of adjusted
>        R-squared values of joint effect of partial and constraining terms
>        and partial term alone, and it is the same as the adjusted
>        R-squared of component ‘[a] = X1|X2’ in two-component variation
>        partition in ‘varpart’.